# Correct response to copied answers

Tags: discussion

What is the correct response when I answer a question and then someone else answers the exact same answer (same content not verbatim copying) 30 minutes later. Should I downvote the response for no original content or flag it somehow or just let it be and hope my answer gets accepted?

Comment: A link to the situation to show what you mean could help. The answer really depends on the situation and the extent of the copying.

Comment: I'm not referring to a specific case just in general if I feel that someone did not add new content over an existing answer what is the correct response both from the asker's perspective and from the other responders.

Comment: In that case, Benjy, it depends. If they are copying any significant part of your answer verbatim _without linking to your answer and attributing it to you_, flag as "Other" and tell the moderators you feel the user plagerised your answer, link to your answer, and they will review it. If the answer is the _same idea_ but not a direct copy, then judge the post on its own merits. Does it add anything that your answer doesn't cover? Does it explain it in an easier to understand way? Is it more in-depth? If any of those answers are "Yes" then at the very least it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: If it's a trivial answer, you should downvote yourself for not providing more than a trivial answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's within the first few minutes, it could be a matter of two people elaborating and improving their answers and just happening to end up with something similar.

30 minutes though... relatively speaking, that's a lot of time. It's possible (but perhaps improbable) that someone was working on their own answer, stepped away, returned later and finished it up, all without ever noticing your existing answer.

One of the reasons for downvoting is "not useful", and it's really not a useful answer if it just covers the same material, without adding any new information. I'd consider downvoting it for that reason.

Not sure any of the flags would be applicable, unless the answer (in whole or significant part) were an *exact* copy/paste... then a mod flag with an explanation, and a link to the original material (esp in cases where the link is another SO thread or an external site, but even in the same thread too, as it removes any ambiguity in exactly which answer you're referring to).

Comment: OK thanks, I downvoted and asked what he added. He answered (not satisfactorily but whatever) so I removed the downvote.