# I flagged a copy-pasted answer and it got declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, plagiarism

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55634753/7910454) through my review queue and quickly realized that it was a copy of the [most-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55634349/7910454), but posted about 20 minutes later.

I consulted meta to find out what I should do about it and found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291113/correct-response-to-copied-answers):

> Not sure any of the flags would be applicable, **unless the answer (in
>   whole or significant part) were an exact copy/paste... then a mod flag
>   with an explanation**, and a link to the original material (esp in
>   cases where the link is another SO thread or an external site, but
>   even in the same thread too, as it removes any ambiguity in exactly
>   which answer you're referring to).

Accordingly I flagged the answer for moderator review with the comment:

> copy-pasted the answer of *name of user* without the rest of the code around it

I specified that **it is not an exact copy** because the original answer provided the entire code included with the question and explained the answer through-fully while not providing the code he added in a separate code-block of itself. The flagged answer provided only the changes made to the original code with an added:

> that's all...

In my opinion **this qualifies as a copy-paste because I could get from the original answer to the flagged answer by only deleting lines**, but I might be wrong here.

I now am confused that my flag was declined (*"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*) and wonder if there is a guideline I missed or something I did not consider when flagging this post. I feel like if there is any added value by having it in a separate code block, it should have been an edit.

Comment: It's probably not a good answer, but I don't think that this can be called a copy/paste.

Comment: @BDL I would suggest that it adds no additional value which is why I consider it a copy-paste but maybe my understanding of a copy-paste is wrong here. Please elaborate so I can handle something like this correctly in the future.

Comment: The answer is a correct answer to the question, presented in another (though terrible) way. So I guess that answer is perfectly fine **from a moderator perspective**. Moderator flags are meant for situations that can't be handled by the community, but this answer doesn't need to be deleted instantly. If you think the answer doesn't add any value, then downvote it.

Comment: @BDl I don't think we disagree here but I wonder where I should draw the line between copy-paste and bad answer. In this case I could just delete 80% of StefanBob's answer and end up with the flagged one

Comment: Unless they copied most of the original answer, I'd refrain from flagging as a duplicate. If 20% copying would be enough, then almost all answers on debugging questions would be copy-paste.

Comment: from a *text* perspective it's no really a copy/paste but if you are experienced with HTML/CSS you can clearly see that it's the same solution badly written so the copy/paste isn't trivial.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Copy-paste means exactly that: Copy text, then paste it. Providing the same (or a very similar) solution is usually fine. Also note, that most of the code (expect for the numbers and the max-height)  is from the question.

Comment: @BDL which is the case here, such solution is something very easy to find without the need of doing a copy/paste. So probably the user didn't even take the time to read old answers before answering. (all the answers are already talking about `100vh`)

Comment: @MiXT4PE I would suggest replying to that answer with a link to this page, that would make a rather fair discussion rather than speculations, also if you think an answer is copied add that in comments to the answer then and there, that helps everyone, if someone really did copy, they won't again because they knows they might get caught, if they didn't they will have the chance to explain themself.

Answer (score 4):

It's entirely possible (and very likely) to arrive to these three lines of CSS

```css
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

withouth plagiarizing anyone. It's a low quality answer alright, but it's impossible to prove this user didn't arrive to this answer independently.

The rule itself comes from the question, and there are various answers that tread the same path in this question.

I believe it's more likely that another user saw a low-hanging-fruit question and answered succintly and poorly. That would have taken less effort than going through the other answer and decide which three lines to copy separately.

The flag was correctly declined IMO.

Comment: I'm confused. How can anything qualify as copy-paste if the possibility of having the same thought at a later time is an excuse? I thought anyone answering should first review the answers already provided and check if his/her idea has already been suggested

Comment: The complexity of the solution matters. I don't believe three lines of kinda obvious CSS raise to the bar.

Comment: @MiXT4PE, It wasn't obvious to me for a long time, nor is it documented, but the bar for plagiarism is set high. Even 5-6 lines perfectly replicated may be deemed a "coincidence" if posted within 30 minutes.